# pod install not working in Mac M1 Silicon

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

```
(base) sameer@Sameers-Air ios % pod installl                    
Traceback (most recent call last):
    16: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    15: from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    12: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     8: from /Users/sameer/.gem/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     5: from /Users/sameer/.gem/gems/activesupport-5.2.5/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.0/lib/bigdecimal.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.0/lib/bigdecimal.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.0/lib/bigdecimal.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.0/lib/bigdecimal.bundle (LoadError)
```

Comment: Not an answer, but in general, I've had trouble installing anything below Ruby 2.7.2 in M1

Comment: how to remove this version and install ruby 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble installing anything below Ruby 2.7.2 in M1 Silicon.

It seems `cocoapods` is just a ruby gem, so installing RVM to install a different Ruby version should work for you.

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install ruby-2.7.2
gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

`arch -x86_64 pod install`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.